# Can ubuntu be installed in intel kabylake 7th gen processor?

Tags: drivers, system-installation, kernel, graphics, intel

I am using a 7th generation i5 processor(7200,2.50 ghz).The processor also have intel hd graphics 620 and nvidia geforce 940mx 2gb graphics card. I read previously that only windows 10 can be installed to this specific processor.

Is it true no version of ubuntu can be used with this processor?

If it's possible to install ubuntu using this processor, what additional steps other than the normal installation process should I undertake to get Ubuntu working?

Comment: you should have no problem if you use a recent kernel. you might have trouble with the Intel iGPU + dGPU Optimus setup

Comment: Hi @user682998 ! This is not regarding the question itself, but could you please share which laptop are you using with this config? I am asking this because I'd like to  buy this laptop too.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/dmi/4103/dmi%3AIntel%28R%29Core%28TM%29i5-7200UCPU%402.50GHz/), I'd say that that processor is fine for use with Ubuntu.  Is yours one of the systems listed?

Apparently there is a bug in the 16.04 kernel that can cause a problem with the Skylake range of processors, but it seems there is a fairly straightforward fix for it:

- Update the kernel to version 4.4.0–18
- Add `intel_pstate=disable` to your kernel command line

A discussion of this fix [can be found here](https://www.quora.com/Does-Ubuntu-support-Intel-Skylake-processors).

Hope that helps.

Comment: What's the *straightforward fix*? Without more info, this is basically a link-only answer

Answer (score 1):

First off, Skylake is Intel's 6th generation of processors, and their numbers start with a 6. So, you are probably using an i5-7200U processor, which is actually a 7th generation processor (as you said) which is sold under the code name Kaby Lake (and not Skylake).

Microsoft said they were only going to support Kaby Lake (7th gen) processors on Windows 10 and no other operating systems - but this is a Microsoft statement, concerning Windows 7 and 8, which does not concern Ubuntu or any other *nix system. See for instance [PCWorld news link](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3035537/windows/microsofts-killing-skylake-support-early-for-windows-7-pcs-but-not-windows-server.html).

You should be fine using Ubuntu, if necessary using sempaiscuba's bugfix.

Comment: yes, i made a mistake by writing my processor is skylake ,actualy it is kevylack,and sorry for that.